# Why does Leaflet with provider tiles not draw markers as expected?

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, leaflet-r

I'm working with Leaflet maps in Shiny for R. I'm producing a map with some markers on it. When I use `addTiles ()` for my base map, everything works as expected. However with `addProviderTiles ()`, the markers don't appear on the map. Only after I trigger an action that causes them to be redrawn, they show up as I would expect them.

This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the vignettes, so I'm not sure if it's a bug or I'm missing some parameter options.

I made a reproducible example. If you run it as is, the markers will appear normally. If you comment line 13 and uncomment line 14, the markers won't work initially. I added an `observer ()` that redraws the markers when you click on the map.

```
library(shiny)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage (
                leafletOutput("map", width="80%", height="800px"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      print ("render tiles")
      b <- bbox (breweries91)
      leaflet (breweries91) %>%
      addTiles () %>%
#      addProviderTiles (providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds (b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4])
      })

  observe ({
      print ("make markers")
      leafletProxy ("map", data = breweries91) %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers ()
      cl <- input$map_click
      if (!is.null (cl))
          print ("click")
      })
}
shinyApp (ui, server)
```

**Edit** software versions:

- Ubuntu: 16.04.2
- Mozilla Firefox 52.0.1
- R: 3.3.3
- leaflet: 1.1.0
- shiny: 1.0.0

Comment: your code worked fine for me! I commented line 13 and uncommented line 14, I deleted the observer and added the line `addAwesomeMarkers()` to the `server` function. I tried runing it in Window and External (*RStudio 1.0.136*) an everything seems to work fine. I'm using *leaflet 1.1.0*, *shiny 1.0.0*, *sp 1.2-4*.

Comment: The problem is that if I draw the markers inside `renderLeaflet`, the entire map has to be reloaded if the markers change. That's why they need to be placed in the observer.

Comment: I don't understand: 1) _I made a reproducible example. If you run it as is, the markers will appear normally._ __That's right!__ _If you comment line 13 and uncomment line 14, the markers won't work initially_, __doing that the markers work initially in my case!__. I don't know how can I help you. I'm using `leaflet` version 1.1.0 and `shiny` 1.0.0.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the same versions, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else then. I'll try it on some other setup tomorrow. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: are you using rstudio? Maybe check the browser you are using to watch the map. And enable javascript.

Comment: I did some more testing now, turns out Firefox is the culprit! On every other browser it worked just fine. Thanks for your help anyway. If you write a short answer, I can accept it and you can collect those sweet, sweet bounty points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **RStudio IDE**, your code worked fine in the *Viewer Pane*. However, it didn't worked using **Firefox 52.0.1** browser.

Commenting the `observer()` function and adding `addAwesomeMarkers ()` to the `renderLeaflet({})` worked fine in **Firefox 52.0.1** browser. I think **Firefox 52.0.1** browser was right, because if you are using an `observer` function that mean it will draw the markers after the `input$map_click` action was done and never before that.

One property of the `observer` function is:

> "An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive values and call reactive expressions ..." (from Shiny package documentation)

Try the suggested code below from your reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage (leafletOutput("map", width = "80%", height = "800px"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    print ("render tiles")
    b <- bbox (breweries91)
    leaflet (breweries91) %>%
      # addTiles () %>%
      addProviderTiles (providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers () %>%
      fitBounds (b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4])
  })

  # observe ({
  #   print ("make markers")
  #   leafletProxy ("map", data = breweries91) %>%
  #     addAwesomeMarkers ()
  #   cl <- input$map_click
  #   if (!is.null (cl))
  #     print ("click")
  # })
}
shinyApp (ui, server)
```

Also, if you want to preserve the `observe` function but not to draw the markers at the begining, you can use it in this way:

```
observe ({
     print ("observe function called")
  #   leafletProxy ("map", data = breweries91) %>%
  #   addAwesomeMarkers ()
     cl <- input$map_click
     if (!is.null (cl))
       print ("click")
   })
```